# React Native with Native Base tabs not rendering

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using the native base extension for my react native app. I am running the code on my iOS simulator.

I have been following this:
http://nativebase.io/docs/v2.0.0/components#tabs

My code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header,Content, Tab, Tabs } from 'native-base';
import Profile from './Profile';
import Posts from './Posts';
export default class ProfileRoot extends Component {

render(){
 return (
     <Container>
     <Header hasTabs />
     <Tabs>
         <Tab heading="Profile">
             <Profile />
         </Tab>
         <Tab heading="Posts">
             <Posts />
         </Tab>
     </Tabs>
     </Container>
 );
 }
}
```

Both the Profile and Posts components render fine individually(there is not much in them anyway other than a few buttons). I am sure native base is installed properly as I have rendered other components such as buttons.

I get the following error:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `ProfileRoot`.

I already have included the export default class in ProfileRoot. There is something that I am clearly missing what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your issue is related to exporting `Profile` or `Posts` component. Can you show how you are exporting your component?

Comment: Instead of `Profile` and `Posts` component try to insert Button, Text or any other component, If it works, than issue might be related to `Profile` or `Posts` not with `Native Base Tabs`.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrap your `<Tabs>` tag by `<Header>` tag, or `<Content>` tag.
Example:
`<Header><Tabs>…</Tabs></Header>`

Answer (score -1):

try to wrap the tabs and header with **view** tag and style with flex: 1